# for and while loop using break,pass,continue.I don't know where I should go next

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to Python and Stackoverflow in general, so sorry if my formatting sucks and I'm not good at English. But I am stuck with this code.

```
test = True
a = True
total = 0
t = 0
while test:
    n = int(input('Width (7-10): '))
    if n<7 or n>10:
        print('Invalid Number!')
        total += 1
    if n>=7 and n<=10:
        break
while a:
    c = int(input('Border (1-3): '))
    if c<1 or c>3:
        print('Invalid Number!')
        t += 1
    if c>=1 and c<=3:
        break
```

This is the result.

```
Width (7-10): 5
Invalid Number!
Width (7-10): 10
Border (1-3): 0
Invalid Number!
Border (1-3): 2
```

And this is the result that I want.

```
Width (7-10): 5
Invalid Number!
Width (7-10): 10
Border (1-3): 0
Invalid Number!
Border (1-3): 2
**********
**********
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
**********
**********
```

I don't know how to make the square.

Comment: so what? print two lines of `10` stars, print `2` stars followed by `10-2*2` spaces and again`2` stars - do that `10-2*2` times, then `2` lines with `10` stars again.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have written to print the square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly**, you can simply write

```
while True:
```

Instead of

```
a = True
while a:
```

**Secondly**, you don't use total or t anywhere. You can delete them.

**Thirdly**, if x has to belong to [a, b], you can write

```
if a <= x <= b:
```

**Fourthly**, you can use else statement instead of negation of if. Also, when you have break in if statement, the code below won't be executed if statement is true (it will break), so you even don't have to use any else here.

**The last part** you can make by simple iteration in for loop and multiplying or adding strings (e.g. 5*'a' = 'aaaaa')

```
while True:
    width = int(input('Width (7-10): '))
    if 7 <= width <= 10:
        break
    print('Invalid Number!')

while True:
    border = int(input('Border (1-3): '))
    if 1 <= border <= 3:
        break
    print('Invalid Number!')

for _ in range(border):
    print(width*'*')

for _ in range (width - 2*border):
    print(border*'*' + (width-2*border)*' ' + border*'*')

for _ in range(border):
    print(width*'*')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by the following code:

```
for i in range(n):
   if i < c or i >= n-c:
        print("*"*n)
    else:
        print("*"*c + " "*(n-(c*c)) + "*"*c)
```

This iterates through a `for` loop with the range being the width entered earlier (`n` in this case). By testing if you are at the first/last few iterations (as determined by the border, or `c` in this case), you can print the border. If not, you can print the necessary stars with the required spacing.

You print the required amount of stars by multiplying the string as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i am totally lost, i don't know how u expect

```
**********
**********
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
**********
**********
```

that when u haven't written any code that will output that result, but what u could do is that before u break in the last while loop paste this

```
dummy = ''
for line in range(1, n + 1):
if line <= c or line > n - c:
    dummy = ''.join(['*'] * n)
    print(dummy)
    dummy = ''
else:
    dummy = ''.join(['*'] * c)
    dummy = dummy + ''.join([' '] * (n - 2*c))
    dummy = dummy + ''.join(['*'] * c)
    print(dummy)
```

please respond if it helped i spent some time on this, and here is ur final code

```
a = True
total = 0
t = 0
while test:
    n = int(input('Width (7-10): '))
    if n<7 or n>10:
        print('Invalid Number!')
        total += 1
    if n>=7 and n<=10:
        break
while a:
    c = int(input('Border (1-3): '))
    if c<1 or c>3:
        print('Invalid Number!')
        t += 1
    if c>=1 and c<=3:
       for line in range(1, n + 1):
    if line <= c or line > n - c:
        dummy = ''.join(['*'] * n)
        print(dummy)
        dummy = ''
    else:
        dummy = ''.join(['*'] * c)
        dummy = dummy + ''.join([' '] * (n - 2*c))
        dummy = dummy + ''.join(['*'] * c)
        print(dummy)

      break
```